# How Do You Find The Dimensions of A Document in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to find the dimensions of an imported document in Illustrator? For example, if you drag a SVG into Illustrator (On Mac)/open a pre-made SVG, it doesn't necessarily tell you the dimensions of the document itself. If you wanted to recreate the document size, how would you do so?

Comment: Removed SVG tag, the question is not specific to one document type

Answer (score 23):

Option 1.  Load the graphic into Illustrator, select the artboard tool

[image]

and click and hold one of the corners, this will display a little tooltip with the height and width.

[image]

---

Option 2.

Click Window> Artboards. On the side a little artboards pane should appear, click the dropdown menu

[image]

then click "Artboard options." This will give you a dialog box with width and height displayed in the units set in Preferences (Edit> Preferences> Units...)

:)

Comment: I think as far as the first solution goes, it's more "click and wiggle" than click and hold, if user clicks and holds perfectly still the info doesn't appear

Answer (score 7):

[image]

When you click on Artboard Tool (Shift + O) you can able to see this on right top. :)

Comment: Hi Rahiem, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I like this answer better, I think it's faster